# mat-tab(s) containing mat-accordion(s)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following structure:

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab>
        <component-1>
    <mat-tab>
        <component-2>
```

Each `component-1` and `component-2` has a `mat-accordion`:

```
<mat-accordion multi="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
        [expanded]="expandedItems.includes(i)">
```

Now, initially when I am in tab 1, the panels are collapsed.  Then I expand one panel.  Next I go to tab 2.  The panels in tab 2 are initially collapsed.  Then I expand one panel.

Then I go back to tab 1.  I see that the panel collapsed.  This cannot be because I am checking if `expandedItems` include this panel.  I am sure that the `expandedItems` includes this panel because I use the same check on styling my `mat-expansion-panel-header`.  I put a specific style on the header when the panel is in `expandedItems`.

Also, same thing happens when I go back to tab 2.  The panel is also collapsed.

Why the panel collapsed even if I expanded it initially.  The content `height` becomes 0 and `visibility` becomes hidden.  This though happens only once.  After seeing those panels collapsed, I click on the panel.  But it didn't move from being collapsed.  It is as if it was expanded but it really was collapsed.  So I click on the header again and it expanded.  Then succeeding change from one tab to another, the panels stay expanded, which is my expected behavior.

**UPDATE**

```
<mat-accordion multi="true">
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [expanded]="expandedItems.includes(i)"
                     (opened)="openPanel(i)" (closed)="closePanel(i)">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title [class.open-panel-title-color]="expandedItems.includes(i)">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    <div [class.table-expanded]="expandedItems.includes(i)"
                     [class.table-collapsed]="!expandedItems.includes(i)"></div>
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

`openPanel` and `closePanel` will just add and remove from expandedItems.

CSS:

```
.table-expanded {
  position: relative;
  height: 517px;
}

.table-collapsed {
  height: unset;
}
```

I need to update the CSS `table-collapsed` and `table-expanded`, because the content inside each div varies.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce your issue, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3jo6l-nxf8tg?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html

Comment: I've also put an example together (including having the tab content as separate components - `component-one` and `component-two` and including the CSS above, but I can't reproduce the issue either: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-28s35p?file=app%2Fcomponent-one.html

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem ?